# ProtocolUnknownError when using wkhtmltopdf to convert HTML to PDF in Symfony 5 with KnpSnappyBundle

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use the KnpSnappyBundle in my Symfony 5 application to convert an HTML page to PDF using wkhtmltopdf. However, I am getting the following error:

Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError

I have checked the URL and it is correct and accessible. I have also checked the file permissions for the wkhtmltopdf binary file and the temporary files generated during the conversion process, and they are readable and writable.

Here is my Error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```php
<?php

namespace Kritek\BillingBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Path;
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
use Kritek\BillingBundle\KritekBillingBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

#[AsController]
final class TestInvoicePdfController extends AbstractController
{
    private $knpSnappyPdf;

    public function __construct(Pdf $pdf)
    {
        $this->knpSnappyPdf = $pdf;
    }


    #[Route('/test/invoicepdf', name: "kritek_billing_testinvoicepdf_index", priority: 100)]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $this->pdfToHtmlAction();
        return $this->render('@KritekBilling/test-invoice-pdf.html.twig');
    }

    private function pdfToHtmlAction(): void
    {
        $pdfName = uniqid() . "-" . "generated.pdf";
        try {
            $this->knpSnappyPdf->generateFromHtml(
                $this->renderView('@KritekBilling/test-invoice-pdf.html.twig'),
                $pdfName,
            );
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th;
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched for a solution to this problem, but I couldn't find any relevant information. How can I fix this issue? Thank you in advance for your help."

I have tried setting the `enable-local-file-access` to true.

Comment: It is talking about `about` and a protocol, which makes me think it is hitting a URL such as `about:config` or similar, somehow

Comment: Could you add also the Twig template used?